Summarizing unique values (unique records) in formula based on filters
A bit hard to describe what I am trying to do but I am stuck and seeking help.
Before I say anything: Here is the exercise sheet so it's easier to understand what I am trying to do:
Exercise Sheet
I have a report that shows a list of bookings by rep and their quota.
Each record type includes the quota of that month. So if a rep sells 2 products in one month, I will have his quota for that month appear twice in that report.
In a cell I want to reflect that quota for that particular months (ignoring how many times it appears for that month, I just want to return it one value). With some help I managed to do this with this formula:
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(F$2:F;A$2:A=K$3;(D$2:D>=I5)*(D$2:D<=J5));1);"")
However, in another cell I would like to return the some of the unique values for the entire year. I am struggling how to do so. (See red marked area of my exercise sheet)
So my report shows a quota of $100,000 for May for Susan. That quota appears two times in the report. And the quota for November is $90,000 and it appears one time. Then I want that cell to return $190,000 as quota for the entire year. I need it to summarize the unique monthly quota values.
Can someone hel?

Use MAP() function to iterate all cells of date ranges, then sum up all filtered values. I have just used your formula inside MAP() then finally summed it. Try-
=SUM(MAP(I5:I10;LAMBDA(x;IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(F$2:F;A$2:A=J$4;Month(D$2:D)=Month(x));1);0))))



Hello Harun! Thank you very much. Is there a possibility to use the date filter (cell I16 and J16)? Let's say I were to change these two cells to reflect only a certain time period, rather than just taking everything from my report (which is what your formula is doing)

@A.Be That should be possible. Then you must change year from 2024 to matching year of column G.
